# takePicture method take long delay (3s to 4s) before didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I use a CameraOverlayView to customize the default camera view in my application but i have a problem with takePicture method, it takes more than 3s before the method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo execution. Is it a problem of image processing or not?

Thank you.

Comment: may be your mobile internal storage almost full

Comment: I don't think so bhanu, because i have 12Go of free storage and my photo gallery is empty. Thank you :).

Comment: i think, there is a memory management problem which leads in slow in calling didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method. check once

Comment: did anybody get a solution for this. as am also facing the same problem